# How to input values into database and collect the new id to store in php/html?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

I just can't figure out how to solve this problem using php to show on a web page.

1. When a user inputs values into "navn" and "kommentar" on my webpage. I will save these into two values. The "navn" value shall be saved into the database table "bruker" where "bruker_id" is auto increment. Then I want to get back which bruker_id the "navn" was saved under.

--> INSERT INTO bruker (navn) VALUES (*inserted name from user*);

1. Using the "bruker_id" and the "kommentar" I want to save into the table "kommentar" all the relevant information. Timestamp shall be current time and attraksjons_id is saved in a URL parameter called attraksjoner in Dreamweaver.

--> SELECT bruker.bruker_id FROM bruker WHERE bruker.navn = *inserted name from user*;
--> INSERT INTO attraksjon (bruker_id, attraksjons_id, kommentar, tidsstempel) VALUES (*collected bruker_id from user, URL parameter attraksjoner from dreamweaver, comment collected from form, automated timestam*);

Thank you in advance for your answer.

My database is as following:

Tablenavn: attraksjon
Primary key: attraksjons_id
attributes: attraksjons_navn, generell_info

---- Relation many-to-many table ----

Created many-to-many 
table reisetips, 
primary keys: bruker_id, attraksjons:id 
attributes: kommentar, tidsstempel

--- Next tabel which is connected to attraksjon with many-to-many relation ----
Table name: kommentar
Primary keys: bruker_id
attributes: navn

My form consists of a text field for "navn" and one text area for "kommentar".

Comment: Assuming the MySQLi extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

The Mysqli function "insert_id" can be helpfull in your case. 
As described by the documentation : [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Another way to achieve this is by not using auto_increment and manage the ID yourself:
Before Inserting into the database your row, grab the last ID in the table and add one (For Exemple). 
Pay attention that to avoid lock and other concurent write, you'll have to do this using  transaction and prepared statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will look into what you just wrote. The links are helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PDO then PDO::lastInsertId will do the work